# Mini cart, price is showing only for one product

Tags: magento-1.8, cart, addtocart

I added new functionality to add multiple products in cat, but when I add more products and go in mini cart on header, only first added product have price and other are with price 0.00. In the modified cart controller I have added

```
$cart->getQuote()->setTotalsCollectedFlag(false);
```

and after

```
$cart->save();
```

I have  added update cart

```
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->setCartWasUpdated(true);
```

This piece of code, it gives qty of products but not and the prices, still showing only price for one product. And others are 0.00. Can anyone help Please.

Comment: Could you post your complete modified cart controller.

Answer (score 3):

What you could do is try to fire the collection of totals in your quote with the following snippet:

```
$cart->getQuote()->setTotalsCollectedFlag(false)
    ->collectTotals()
    ->save();
```

Answer (score -3):

You are using `getSingleton` Method Please use `getModel` Method.

```
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->setCartWasUpdated(true);
```

After that remove var/session folder. Flush your cache and test.

Hope It will work.

Comment: Does this should look like Mage::getModel('checkout/session')->setCartWasUpdated(true);
if it is I already have tried doesn't work. The point is that when i go to cart mini cart is updating, with full price of all products.